# For multiple instances of a single class in JavaScript, does a function take space for every instance?

Tags: javascript

Consider this class:

```
class A {
  num: number;
  str: string;

  someFunction(){console.log("SomeFunction called!")}
}
```

`someFunction` takes a bit of memory to store. Do we hold this function in memory only once for all instances of class `A`, or every single object created allocates memory to store `someFunction`?

Comment: go with singleton design patter, for your reference go with below ling may this will work for you : https://blog.mgechev.com/2014/04/16/singleton-in-javascript/

Comment: `someFunction` will be defined on the `A.prototype` object and not on the instance of `A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS class internally uses Prototype which shares functions with all instances.

You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain